# How to use GTM without Cocoapod?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to use GTM in an app.
For now, the app is not using CocoaPods, and is not going to use CocoaPods. But GTM requires CocoaPods, and there seem to be no way to install GTM without CocoaPods. But I hope there's a way to use GTM without CocoaPod. Can I?